# jQuery Autocomplete field in Symfony2 with the formType and Doctrine2

Tags: forms, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

I got 2 entities linked by a 'OneToMany' relationship.
One of the entities is the object `City`. The table corresponding to this object includes almost 37000 entries.
When I proceed to the creation of a form to populate the Proprietairy entity in Symfony, I use a FormType which looks like below. It includes a field corresponding to the City Object

```
namespace Immo\BienBundle\Form;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class ProprietaireType extends AbstractType {
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $builder
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('prenom')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('telephone')
        ->add('adresse')
        ->add('city', 'entity', array(
            'class'=>'Immo\BienBundle\Entity\City', 
            'property'=>'city'));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'immo_bienbundle_proprietairetype';
    }
}
```

The form renders a combobox. populated by the 36000 cities and takes incredibly long to load. I have tried the option fetch="extra_lazy", but it is still not efficient enough.
My idea was to create a form with an input field working with ajax and displaying the list of the cities after the user provides 2 letters. I would appreciate any help from the community to create the needed relationship with my Object when validating.

Answer (score 2):

Use https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/1951
Soon in the v2.1 I hope...

Answer (score 0):

You can use my bundle https://github.com/shtumi/ShtumiUsefulBundle to get ajax autocomplete form type